# "polymer build" inconsistently copies extraDependencies

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-cli

I'm using polymer-cli 1.5.7 on different projects. In some projects, the `extraDependencies` `"client/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/*.js"` copies all 8 JS files into `build/es5-bundled`, `build/es6-bundled`, and `build/es6-unbundled`. In another very similar project (both modeled on the Shop app), with the same `extraDependencies` in `polymer.json`, not all JS files are copied into `build/es5-bundled` and `build/es6-bundled`. Both are missing `webcomponents-loader.js` and `build/es5-bundled` is also missing `custom-elements-es5-adapter.js`. All 8 JS files are in `build/es6-unbundled`.

Naturally the project won't run without `webcomponents-loader.js`, which I must copy in by hand.

What could be wrong with my setup or the CLI?

Comment: Even dropping `.js` from the end of `extraDependencies` `"client/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/*.js"` fails to copy these files using `polymer build`.

Comment: I see that I'm not alone: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/911

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check your `"entrypoint"` or `"shell"` in polymer.json?

I had similar problems with bundling until I realized I changed my primary app component in index.html without modifying setup json.

Comment: Alas, no. Both read `"entrypoint": "index.html"` and both have the same `<body>` elements in `index.html`.